# Console logger called twice on one mousedown

Tags: jquery, plugins, onmousedown

I am experiencing a strange problem with jQuery's onmousedown. I have a plugin, to which you can assign buttons and add some options, like so:

```
$.lollipopbutton(".buttons button", {
    bubble_color: "rgba(0,0,0,1)"
});
```

One thing that happens in this plugin is that when you click the buttons, an animation will trigger. However, I only want to allow this animation to be triggered x times at a time. Therefore, I added the option `maxClicks` (default = 10 for test purposes). Additionally, every button gets a jQuery data element to keep track of a counter:

```
counter = $this.data("counter") || 0;
```

we can then compare the counter to the maxClicks option:

```
if (counter <= args.maxClicks) {}
```

and put the function we only want to execute twice at a time in there:

```
        if (counter <= args.maxClicks) {
            // Do stuff
            $this.data("counter", ++counter);
            console.log(counter);

            setTimeout(function () {
                $this.children(".bubble:first").remove();
                if (!$this.children(".bubble").length) {
                    $this.data("counter", --counter);
                }
            }, totalTimeout);
        }
    });
```

But the strange part is that `console.log()` returns twice on each click, always two subsequent numbers (e.g. 1 & 2, 3 & 4, 5 & 6 and so on).

I tried everything, but I couldn't isolate the problem. What am I missing here? The plugin (wip) can be found [here in a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/afw7fumu/33/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is being called twice because within the `lollipopbutton` function you attach a `mousedown` handler. You call `lollipopbutton` like

```
$.lollipopbutton(".buttons button", {
    bubble_color: "rgba(0,0,0,1)"
});

$.lollipopbutton(".buttons button.white", {
    text_overlay: false
});
```

This will attach the `mousedown` handler **twice**.

Comment: I thought I tested it, apparently I didn't.. Thanks. Any idea how to bypass this problem?

Comment: @BramVanroy, why not have the on mousedown handler initialized outside lollipopbutton?